# How to use LIKE with subquery?

Tags: sqlite, regex

In a SQLITE3 DB, I have a table A with a column 'word' containing search words that partially match a column in another table B.

I'd like to SELECT all rows FROM table B WHERE B.name LIKE %any_of_the_words_in_a.word%';

My first idea was to use a REGEX, but I can't get it to work with REGEX and a subquery.

Comment: `SELECT b.* FROM tablename AS b WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM words AS w WHERE b.name LIKE CONCAT('%',wb.word,'%'));`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is what you are after, no need for Regex. It's just a correlated subquery, with the only difference being the `LIKE` condition instead of the common equality condition:

```
SELECT b.* 
FROM tablename AS b 
WHERE EXISTS 
      ( SELECT * 
        FROM words AS w 
        WHERE b.name LIKE '%' || w.word || '%'
      ) ;
```

Comment: They might need REGEX instead of LIKE to ensure that a word is used as a whole word and not as part of a word. But the query would essentially be the same as this, of course.

Answer (score -3):

```
SELECT e.id, count(a.salary)
FROM (subquery here that returns "id"
     ) e left outer join
     TableA a
     on a.comment like '%'||e.id||'%'
group by e.id;
```

Comment: Welcome to the site. It would be helpful if you edited your answer to explain why you've adopted this solution.